# ¿Como detectar si JavaScript esta activado en el navegador del visitante de mi pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy creando un sitio web en donde es prioritario el uso de javascript, asi que quisiera saber como detectar si el navegador esta ejecutando javascript al visitar mi sitio, y si nó, direccionarlo o darle la opcion para activarlo inmediatamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el tag `<noscript>`, para redireccionarlo a una pagina que le informe que **Javascript esta desactivado.**

```
<noscript>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=redireccionarPagina.html">
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 2):

usa la etiqueta `<noscript>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Detectando si javascript está habilitado</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("tiene js activado");
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <h1>Comprobando si javascript está habilitado</h1>
        <div class="deshabilitado">
            <img src="images/error.png" alt="Javascript deshabilitado" />
            Javascript está deshabilitado en su navegador web.<br />
            Por favor, para ver correctamente este sitio,<br />
            <b><i>habilite javascript</i></b>.<br />
            <br />
            Para ver las instrucciones para habilitar javascript<br />
            en su navegador, haga click 
            <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/es/" 
            target="_blank">aquí</a>.
        </div>
    </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```