# cuando no funciona jQuery?

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-validate

Tengo una duda y quisiera la guia, comentarios de algun experto o programador que usa frecuentemente jQuery.

Quiero capturar algunos eventos del lado del cliente utilizando jQuery en una aplicación MVC C# ademas de utilizar jQuery datatable para mostrar información desde la base de datos, pero mi confusión es: en caso que el usuario tenga javascript desactivado, el jQuery sigue funcionando? en caso de ser asi que tan frecuente es hoy en dia.

Utilizo vista fuertemente tipadas por lo que utilizo dataannotations ademas que se que toda aplicacion debe pasar validaciones en el lado del servidor pero quisiera saber que hacer en caso que jQuery no funcione.

Gracias por la guia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es muy comun que navegadores por defecto tengan desactivado el uso de Javascript. solo navegadores que se ejecuten desde el servidor por seguridad y otros aficionados a la informatica

Answer (score 0):

JQuery es una biblioteca de JavaScript.
Si el cliente tiene desactivado JavaScript no hay nada que hacer.

Answer (score -1):

Con esta respuesta puedes ver si Js esta habilitado...Jquery como decian arriba es una dependencia de JS si este no esta habilitado Jquery no va a funcionar....revisa aqui: [¿Como detectar si JavaScript esta activado en el navegador del visitante de mi pagina?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43652/como-detectar-si-javascript-esta-activado-en-el-navegador-del-visitante-de-mi-p)